# Error when simulating spice model in OrCAD PSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, spice, orcad

I am trying to simulate a circuit based on TS522 op-amp using OrCAD PSpice 16.5. The manufacturer's website did not have a model for this op-amp, and I had to look for it elsewhere. I was able to find one and import it into my OrCAD project, however, the PSpice simulator throws en error, every time I am trying to simulate the netlist. The error says:

```
ERROR(ORPSIM-16371): Extra text on line
```

The model file is located [here](http://www.elektronikschule.de/~krausg/Spice_Model_CD/Vendor%20List/STMicroelectronics/Standard%20Linear%20ICs/Spice/ts522.txt).

Could anyone help me with this error? I am not very familiar with detailed of Spice syntax, just have the overall idea what netlists are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess is that it might refer to the (analog) on this line:

```
 .SUBCKT TS522 1 3 2 4 5 (analog)
```

Try removing that and see if it works.

Checking further down, there is also a problem on this line:

```
 E1 50 40 51 0 1 E2 40 39 52 0 1
```

It should be:

```
 E1 50 40 51 0 1 
 E2 40 39 52 0 1
```

I just tried it in LTSpice with these two changes and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Thanks. I did the E1-E2 line split, and it stopped complaining.